# How metadata API works?

Tags: post-meta, meta-query

**Update 2**: *Check out @NateWr method using `add_post_meta` with the default post*:

```
add_post_meta( 1, 'my_items', 1 );
add_post_meta( 1, 'my_items', 2 );
add_post_meta( 1, 'my_items', new \stdClass );  

var_dump(get_post_meta(1, 'my_items', true));
echo "<br><br>";
var_dump(get_post_meta(1));
echo "<br><br>";

$GLOBALS['wp_object_cache']->stats();
```

And the results:

```
string(1) "1" 

array(1) {
  ["my_items"]=>array(3) {
    [0]=> string(1) "1"
    [1]=> string(1) "2"
    [2]=> string(19) "O:8:"stdClass":0:{}"
  }
}
```

This time, it hits the cache but the meta value is different. Now, if I don't know `meta_key` and I just use only post ID to retrieve and parse post meta manually, it's obvious that i will get *wrong* value.

---

**Update 1**: *Check out @NateWr method using `update_post_meta` with the default post*:

```
update_post_meta(1, 'my_items', 1);
update_post_meta(1, 'my_items', 2);
update_post_meta(1, 'my_items', 3);

var_dump( get_post_meta(1) );

echo "<br><br>";

$GLOBALS['wp_object_cache']->stats();
```

Results:

```
array(1) {
  ["my_items"]=>array(1) {
    [0]=>string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

Look like `Cache Hits` doesn't change and WordPress still return an meaningless array as `meta_value`. Or I missed something?

---

**Question**:

I'm trying to avoid extra queries on templates by pre-fetching necessary data while the `WP_Query` retrieving posts. This is basically how it looks like:

```
add_filter('the_posts', function($posts, $query)
{
  if ( !is_admin() ) {
    $mapper = new Vendor\PostMapper($GLOBALS['wpdb']);
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
      $post->post_link = get_permalink($post);
      $post->post_meta = $mapper->getMetadata($post);
      $post->post_thumbnail = $mapper->getThumbnail($post);
      ...
    }
  }

  return $posts;
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 2);
```

Everything works fine but I feel unease while parsing metadata. By using [metadata API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API), if I don't specify `meta_key`, meta values are always arrays of only one element such as:

```
array(3) {
  ["_edit_last"]=>array(1) {
    [0]=>string(1) "1"
  }
  ["_edit_lock"]=>array(1) {
    [0]=>string(12) "1467358332:1"
  }
  ["_thumbnail_id"]=>array(1) {
    [0]=>string(3) "767"
  }
}
```

I think I will never be able to know all `meta_key`. I also have no ideas why WordPress need to do that. The arrays look meaningless and it bothers me a lot.

So, given that `meta_key` isn't required and I don't specify `meta_key`, I really need your help to understand:

**Q1**: Can one `meta_key` have multiple `meta_value`? If not, why WordPress need to use an meaningless array as output for `meta_value`?

**Q2**: Why WordPress don't unserialize all serialized meta values?

Comment: I didn't include this in my answer, but typically a `WP_Query` retrieves post metadata and stores it in object cache. That means that you can call `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_first_meta_key', true);` and then call `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_second_meta_key', true );` and keep making calls like that, and you won't be hitting the database every time. It will go to the object cache for the meta values. I'm not sure your exact application, but that may circumvent the issue for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1**
Yes, you can store serialized arrays as a single meta key, eg:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_items', array( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
```

Furthermore, you can store multiple values against a single meta key, eg:

```
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_items', 1 );
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_items', 2 );
```

The latter is preferred because meta queries can be more efficiently performed against them.

In the first example, there is a single row in the `post_meta` table. In the second example, there are two rows.

So, in the second example, you can perform a query for posts which have a `my_item` meta value of `2` without having to pull out and unserialize every `my_item` entry in the database.

Many people, myself included, learned this the hard way.

**Q2**
I'm sorry I can't answer the *why*, though I do know that serialization and unserialization can have performance implications for large data sets.

Comment: Thanks you! I have just check out your method and updated my question but somehow, WordPress still return an meaningless array.

Comment: Sorry, I should have used `add_post_meta`, not `update_post_meta`. Updating will obviously override the existing value. You need to add if you want multiple values attached to a single key like in example 2. That's also why `update_post_meta` lets you pass a `prev_value` argument: that way you can update just the one meta value instead of all of them.

Comment: Hey @NateWr, I have updated the question again. Look like I still misunderstand something...

Comment: The results you post under Update 2 look correct and as expected. Maybe if you clarify what you expected them to be I can clear up the confusion.

Comment: Thanks @NateWr! I'm wondering how to parse metadata without knowing about meta keys because the results of with and without a `meta_key` are different.